Cut out rotated rectangle shape
I'm trying to cut out a region from a rectangle covering two points.
I can do this manually doings some trigonometry of course but I would like a solution where I can plug in just two points and it cuts a "broad line" between the points out of the shading
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[fill] (-2,2) circle (.25cm);
  \draw[fill] (-0,0) circle (.25cm);

  \draw[fill=black,fill opacity=.3,,even odd rule]
  (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3)
  % The following I would like to be auto-computed from the two points
  (-2,2.5) -- (-2.5,2) -- (0,-0.5) -- (0.5,0) -- (-2,2.5) 
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



If you use a rotated rectangle instead of a line, maybe an inverse clip can help https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12010/how-can-i-invert-a-clip-selection-within-tikz

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (p1) at (-2,2);
\coordinate (p2) at (0,0);
\pgfmathsetmacro{\width}{sqrt(0.5)}

\draw[fill] (p1) circle[radius=0.25cm];
\draw[fill] (p2) circle[radius=0.25cm];
\draw[fill=lightgray, even odd rule] 
(-3,-3) rectangle (3,3)
($ 0.5*(p1)!\width cm!180:(p2) + 0.5*(p1)!\width cm!90:(p2) $) --
($ 0.5*(p1)!\width cm!180:(p2) + 0.5*(p1)!\width cm!-90:(p2) $) --
($ 0.5*(p2)!\width cm!180:(p1) + 0.5*(p2)!\width cm!90:(p1) $) --
($ 0.5*(p2)!\width cm!180:(p1) + 0.5*(p2)!\width cm!-90:(p1) $) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



You can use the line style double with line cap=rect. Draw the big dots at the same time:

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzset{bigdot/.style={fill, circle, inner sep=0pt, minimum size=5mm}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate(A) at (-2,2);
\coordinate(B) at (0,0);

  \filldraw[fill opacity=.3](-3,-3) rectangle (3,3);

  \draw[double, double distance=6mm, line cap=rect](A)node[bigdot]{}--(B)node[bigdot]{};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\myrec}[2]{%
    ($(#1)!0.5cm!135:(#2)$) -- ($(#1)!0.5cm!-135:(#2)$) -- ($(#2)!0.5cm!135:(#1)$) -- ($(#2)!0.5cm!-135:(#1)$) -- cycle}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \coordinate (A) at (-2,2);
        \coordinate (B) at (0,0);
        \filldraw (A) circle[radius=0.25];
        \filldraw (B) circle[radius=0.25];
        \filldraw[fill opacity=.3, even odd rule]
        (-3,-3) rectangle (3,3)
        \myrec{A}{B}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

